# iOS tools for debugging dynamic libraries

Tags: ios, xcode, dyld

I am trying to understand how dynamic linking works on iOS 8 and would like to print the location of the resolved libraries when the app launches. Are there any tools for doing this? In crash reports when a dylib is not found there is some info about search paths, but I can't find this info in a non-crashing execution.

Specifically, I am trying to understand a scenario which is working, but which I didn't think would:

- Swift Framework (Foo): `Dynamic Library Install Name` is @rpath/Foo.framework/Foo
- Swift app (Bar): `Runtime Search Paths` is @executable_path/Frameworks

The app does **NOT** have any Embedded Binaries (`General -> Embedded Binaries`), and does **NOT** embed the framework as a bundle resource (`Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources`).

In the generated `Bar.app` folder there is a `Frameworks` directory, but it does not contain `Foo`, and `Foo` is not contained anywhere else within `Bar.app`. I do not see how is it possible for `Foo` to be resolved since the framework is embedded and should be unavailable?

Comment: Be sure to test this on devices, not the simulator, as their linking behaviour is different. I have not delved deeply but it appears the iOS simulator will dynamically link to frameworks outside the app bundle, where iOS Devices will not permit this.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, will make sure to do this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found what I was looking for, as documented by Apple under a document called [Technical Note TN2239 iOS Debugging Magic](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2239/_index.html). In this document there is [a section describing various environment variables](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2239/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010638-CH1-SUBSECTION21) that can bet set which will force the dynamic linker to write out useful debugging information.

After setting these variables in Xcode (`Edit Scheme -> Run -> Arguments -> Environment Variables`) I get detailed information about how and what the linker is resolving to.